# Change image AND image position by using loops [python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to print out images that correspond to a list of names.

I have the following code already:

```
for item in player_hand:
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Images',item.name+'.png')), (100, 100))
```

I want to update the tuple (100,100) so that each new image gets printed to the right of the previous image.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you load the image as you blit, it will be slow. Load your images  before looping into a list/dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to introduce an increasing variable to the loop. For instance

```
for n, item in enumerate(player_hand):
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Images',item.name+'.png')), (100+n*10, 100))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Love it when I learn something new. Thanks @0sh

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
count=0
for item in player_hand:
   screen.blit(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Images',item.name+'.png')), (100+count, 100))
   count=count+distance
```

where distance is how much on the right you need it

this way is the best because you can change how much to move the image each time the loop is repeated by adding the value of an array! (e.g: if you need different distances or have imges of different size)